# Upgrading Hudson to Jenkins: 500 error

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I tried to upgrade from Hudson to Jenkins and I'm getting a "Status Code: 500 error" on the main page. I put in a bug report here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15309 but no one has responded.

Anyone else have an idea of what is going on? I'd really like to convert from Hudson to Jenkins.

Partial stacktrace:

```
Status Code: 500
Exception: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/appserv/devimat/hudson/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.483.jar!/hudson/model/View/index.jelly:44:43: <st:include> Cannot invoke method isEmpty() on null object
Stacktrace:

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/appserv/devimat/hudson/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.483.jar!/hudson/model/View/index.jelly:44:43: <st:include> Cannot invoke method isEmpty() on null object
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyClassTearOff.serveIndexJelly(JellyClassTearOff.java:112)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:127)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:563)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:625)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:659)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:488)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:162)
[...]

Caused by: org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/appserv/devimat/hudson/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.483.jar!/hudson/model/View/index.jelly:44:43: <st:include> Cannot invoke method isEmpty() on null object
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:716)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:282)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:270)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we did it:

1. Install Jenkins on a new server, along with any plugins you like.
2. Assuming you have slave-machines, Install Jenkins-Agents in parallel to your existing ones (Hudson's).
3. Manually copy your jobs from Hudson to Jenkins, reviewing the flow as you go.

I know that sounds tedious, but it is usually much faster than trying to convert the DB of Hudson to the structure required now by Jenkins,
especially as many plugins have changed since the split.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Hudson to Jenkins at this point in time is going to be pretty hard, since the code bases have diverged so much since they split in late 2010.  I'm pretty sure your error is due to an incompatibility in the expected configuration file format between Hudson and Jenkins.

It might help to ensure that you have the latest version of Hudson before upgrading, and then pick a version of Jenkins that was released around the same time, but I can't guarantee that will work.

Comment: I'm running the latest Hudson. I've already found that Jenkins doesn't support cascading jobs, but I have a few jobs in Hudson setup that way. That part is an easy workaround.